# Execute PHP functions from buttons/form on a page

Tags: php, function

I have over 150 functions on a page, below is an example of 3 (the others are named differently and contain different numbers after 'system').

```
function GappsMail1()
{ $doc->root->node->system[0]->setCDATA("1"); }
function GappsMail2()
{ $doc->root->node->system[0]->setCDATA("2"); }
function GappsMail3()
{ $doc->root->node->system[0]->setCDATA("3"); }
```

What I'm wanting to do is run each of the functions depending on what is clicked on the page, for example the above 3 functions will be represented by an "R", "A" and "G", if a user clicks R then "GappsMail1" executes. Is there an easy way to do this? (I'm still learning PHP!). I know the functions work, I just don't know how to create a button to run each one. Thanks

Comment: PHP executes on the server, not in the browser, so your buttons will have to make separate calls to the server in order to execute PHP code.

Comment: I assume the button on the page sends a POST or GET request to the PHP script?

Comment: You couldn't create *one* function `GappsMail($nr)`? :) And how is `$doc` defined inside those functions?

Comment: Cheers guys, these 3 are similar names, but the rest aren't, I know the functions work, I just don't know how to create any kind of button for them to be run (Julian, there is no button yet, that's what I'm needing help with)

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you are doing with this code?

Comment: Kalpit, I am updating an xml file (php 4, we cannot update this), I've run the functions in a php page and they are fine, I'm just creating a front end for people in our IT department to be able to click a button to make a quick change when a system goes down.

Comment: If you want to call an action, then maybe should you use ajax. Create a button, on click it run your ajax who redirect on the route of your wanted action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form for each button

```
<form action='mypage.php' name='func1' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='function' value='R' />
<input type='submit' value='Button R'>
</form>
```

And then in mypage.php (can be the same page as the form)

```
<php
if ($_POST['function']=="R") {
GappsMail1();
}
elseif ($_POST['function']=="A") {
GappsMail2();
}
```

Or, you can call functions directly by their name. This way you don't have to make 150 if-else statements. See [Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). Note that if you call functions directly by name this is a possible exploit hole because the attacker could modify the POST data and execute any function he wants. You need to do some sanity checks first.